# MySQL and EF Core 6 error The LINQ expression could not be translated

Tags: mysql, ef-core-6.0

I recently updated our project from EF Core 2.2.6 to 6.x (along with and upgrade from .NET core 3.1 to .NET 6) and now I'm get errors like the one stated in the title whenever the query gets even a little complicated.  One of those cases is when you add a `GroupBy` clause.  Below is an example of a failing query.

```
_context.MyTable
.Where(a => a.Name.Contains("service"))
.GroupBy(ss => ss.IsServiceSpecific)
```

The entire error is:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet< MyTable >()
> .Where(a => a.Name.Contains("service"))
> .GroupBy(ss => ss.IsServiceSpecific)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch
> to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
> 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

The setup at this [MySQL::Entity Framework Core Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html) URL is exactly what I did (there are only two steps to set it up).  My DI config looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddEntityFrameworkMySQL()
.AddDbContext<MydbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySQL(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    });
```

It will execute simple queries but more complex ones always generate this error.  It says to rewrite the query and force client side evaluation by using `AsEnumerable` or `ToList` but I don't want to drag all that data to the client and I expect that a simple group by can be translated and handled server side.

I did find [one article](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/query-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated/) that talks about this problem but I'm not getting if it's suggesting an actual solution.

This shouldn't be this hard and I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Could you provide more details about error message?

Comment: Have you try to add ***Select*** function after GroupBy?

Comment: @KennetsuRinn  I've updated the question with the entire error.

Answer (score 0):

- Model

```
 

       internal class Post
        {
            public int PostId { get; set; }
            public string? Title { get; set; }
            public string? Content { get; set; }
    
            public int BlogId { get; set; }
        }
```

- DBContext

```
     internal class BloggingContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Post>? Posts { get; set; }
    
            public string DbPath { get; }
    
            public BloggingContext()
            {
                var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    
                DbPath = $"{path}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}blogging.db";
            }
    
            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
                => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
        }
```

- Main

```
 

    internal class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                using (var db = new BloggingContext())
                {
                    var posts = db.Posts.Where(s => s.Title.Contains("Hello")).GroupBy(g => g.BlogId == 1994).Select(s => new { Key = s.Key, Counts = s.Count() }).ToList();
                    foreach (var p in posts)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(p);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

- Conclusion: You might add ***Select*** statement after ***GroupBy***.
  [image]

Comment: I was returning that query in a API method so it was being serialized.  I did add a Select to it just out of curiosity but it still failed.  This is a much simpler example of the code that's in the actual project that I'm working on.  In many of those cases there is a select and sometimes we're creating Dictionaries from the queries.  The simple statements work but anything more complex throws this error.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow If in hurry, you could try to use raw sql execute in ef core. Or you can try to use Dapper to cover this problem.

Comment: I can't convert my entire project over it's quite large.  I just don't understand how this is not working.   One suggestion is to do something like this:  `_context.MyTable.Where(a => .Name.Contains("service")).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(ss => ss.IsServiceSpecific)`.  While this works I believe that it returns all records from the database given the where clause then does the GroupBy on the client.   I have some large datasets that do this and bringing them to the client would not be a good idea plus that's a lot of code to update to "fix" all of them.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow
 Can you move ***groupby condition*** into ***where caluse*** to reduce result size?

Comment: Not sure how you move GroupBy in to a WHERE clause.  Again, I've seen other posts on SO that indicate that in fact EF **will** convert GroupBy to group by in the sql statement.  I don't understand how this is not working.  I even tried this on a test project using SQL server just to see if this was only a MySql problem and while I didn't get an error saying it couldn't translate the LINQ statement it did still fail.  To me this is such a basic query that I think that there must be something simple that I'm not seeing causing the problem.

Comment: @HisDivineShadow
 _context.MyTable.Where(a => .Name.Contains("service") && ss.IsServiceSpecific).ToList()